# MarkLogic Search return document collections

Tags: java, marklogic

Is there a way to **return the collections** of a document if you are using the **search api**?

I could not find a option in the [Query Options Reference](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#chapter) for that use case.

Right now i would have to build my own wrapper around the search api and find the collections of search results by myself:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

let $docs := search:search("query")

return for $doc in $docs
return xdmp:node-collections(doc($doc/search:result/@uri))
```

Edit: This should be also availiable with the marklogic java client api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are using the MarkLogic REST api, you can use the `category` parameter on `/v1/search` to pull up `metadata` instead of content. If you would like to blend it into the search results, you best use a REST transform on `/v1/search` using the `transform` parameter. See also:

https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/search

HTH!

Comment: Well i guess i should have added, that i'm using the Java Client Api. Sorry for that. Thus i am kinda restricted to what is offered in the query options, i guess?

Comment: Java Client Api leverages the REST api, so there might be an option to select the category. I'm not aware unfortunately..

Comment: Afaik there is no way to specify a transform function. See http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/QueryManager.html#search-com.marklogic.client.query.QueryDefinition-T- .

Comment: The category param would be what i want, sadly the Java api offers no way to specify it. But that would definitly be the way to go. I might issue a github ticket. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

To get only document metadata such as collections and not the document content, write and install a server-side transform that takes calls xdmp:node-collections() on the document and constructs a replacement document.  See:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/transforms

Then call the QueryDefinition.setResponseTransform() method to specify the server-side transform:

http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/QueryDefinition.html#setResponseTransform-com.marklogic.client.document.ServerTransform-

before passing the query definition to the DocumentManager.search() method:

http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/document/DocumentManager.html#search-com.marklogic.client.query.QueryDefinition-long-

As a footnote, the DocumentManager.search() method can retrieve both the document metadata and content in a single request without a server-side transform by calling DocumentManager.setMetadataCategories() before searching.  See:

http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/document/DocumentManager.html#setMetadataCategories-java.util.Set-

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Yea, i noticed there is a `setMetadataCategories` method. But it is defined in `DocumentManager`. If you want to use a `QueryManager` there is no way to pass categories.

Comment: I would think DocumentManager.search will do the trick if you just want to retrieve the collections from documents matching a query. Perhaps you need to restate your problem so we can understand what services you need from a QueryManager.

Comment: Someone who is thinking of the input to the document retrieval operation would expect QueryManager to provide the search() method.  Someone who is thinking of the output would expect DocumentManager to provide the search() method. The Java API made the design choice to put the search() method that retrieves documents on DocumentManager.